# MySQL How to obtain the MIN and MAX of the top 100 values in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to find the maximum and minimum value of the top 100 scores in our database.

It seems like it should be simple, but I'm missing something.

I've tried

```
SELECT 
       MAX(BEST_GAME_SCORE) as max_bgs , 
       MIN(BEST_GAME_SCORE) as min_bgs 
FROM user 
WHERE BEST_GAME_SCORE IN (SELECT BEST_GAME_SCORE 
                          FROM user 
                          ORDER BY BEST_GAME_SCORE DESC 
                          LIMIT 100)
```

but... LIMIT doesn't work in a subquery

I've tried using JOIN, but I always get 0 for the MIN where min in the join should not be 0

```
SELECT 
    MAX(user.BEST_GAME_SCORE), 
    MIN(user.BEST_GAME_SCORE) 
FROM user 
  JOIN ( SELECT user.BEST_GAME_SCORE 
         FROM user 
         ORDER BY user.BEST_GAME_SCORE DESC 
         LIMIT 100) latest
```

EDIT:
FOR EXAMPLE
If I have a table with the following scores

```
1000
900
800
700
600
500
400
300
200
100
```

I would like to select the top 5 scores (i.e. 1000,900,800,700,600) but have the query simply return the max and min of that so 1000 and 600. Sorry I thought that was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT MAX(BEST_GAME_SCORE) as max_bgs , MIN(BEST_GAME_SCORE) as min_bgs
from (SELECT BEST_GAME_SCORE
      FROM user
      ORDER BY BEST_GAME_SCORE DESC
      LIMIT 100
     ) u;
```

Comment: gah... thank you that was so easy. I guess I need to understand the difference in when to use WHERE column IN subquery

Comment: @naphier: the difference is between a derived table (in this answer) and an uncorrelated subquery (your attempt).

Comment: Actually this doesn't work, sorry for jumping the gun
ugh sorry, that doesn't seem to work right.
I just tried it on the top 5 and it gives me the MAX and the third highest value. So:
BEST_GAMES_SCORES (the top 5)
500
400
300
200
100

Your query gives 500 and 300

Comment: @naphier should explain  question correctly , according to your present question it answers.

Comment: Thought it was clear. I want the min and max values of the top X scores. I edited with an example so it is more clear. Your query on that database would return 1000 and 800 no Idea why because your query looks sound.

Comment: @naphier . . . This query should do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Holy cow - my mistake!!! I was looking at a list that had some exclusions. Thank you, sorry for the back and forth. I was so befuddled why this wasn't working. Thank you!